# Is postNotificationName guaranteed to dispatch immediately to listeners?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

If i do

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"N" object:self];
NSLog(@"here");
```

The observer is notified synchronously before `NSLog(@"here");` is executed... **if all objects are on the same thread, is this guaranteed to be executed synchronously (immediately)?**

Cannot find this to be explicitly stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, quite well buried though:

> Using the NSNotificationCenter’s postNotification: method and its variants, you can post a notification to a notification center. However, the invocation of the method is synchronous: before the posting object can resume its thread of execution, it must wait until the notification center dispatches the notification to all observers and returns.

Source:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationQueues.html